# Querying hive complex data types like struct in Superset's SQL LAB

Tags: sqlalchemy, hive, apache-superset, pyhive

I have been using [superset](http://superset.incubator.apache.org) to query an external table through hive. This table has columns which are mostly of hive complex data types like the `struct`.
How would I write a query in SQL LAB that does something like below?

```
SELECT header.guid
FROM table1
WHERE guid = 'xxxx'
```

where `header` is of struct data type and `guid` is a member of the header.

The problem as far as I can see is that [pyhive maps](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive/blob/master/pyhive/sqlalchemy_hive.py#L98) the struct data types to string, although not sure how to get around it yet

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by querying hive through prestodb. PrestoDB needed additional parquet config in it's `etc/catalog/hive.properties` catalog:

```
connector.name=hive-hadoop2
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://<hive_url>:9083
hive.parquet-optimized-reader.enabled=true
hive.parquet-predicate-pushdown.enabled=true
```